# $f:D\to D$ is strictly contracting with respect to the hyperbolic metric

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be a non-conformal analytic function from the unit disk to itself. Show that $f$ is strictly contracting with respect to the hyperbolic metric on any subdisk $\{|z|\le r\}$, $0<r<1$. Specifically, show that

$$\rho(f(z_0),f(z_1))\le c\rho(z_0,z_1), \quad |z_0|,|z_1|\le r, c < 1$$

where $\rho(z_0,z_1)$ is the hyperbolic distance from $z_0$ to $z_1$.

**I made some progress, but I got stuck. Here's my progress**:

Let $\gamma$ be the geodesic from $z_0$ to $z_1$. Then
$$
\begin{align}
\rho(f(z_0),f(z_1)) &\le 2\int_{f\circ\gamma} \frac{|dw|}{1-|w|^2}\\
&= 2\int_{\gamma} \frac{|f'(z)||dz|}{1-|f(z)|^2}\\
\end{align}
$$

I thought that maybe I should make a change of variables and use Pick's theorem. However, this didn't get me anywhere. Hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Use compactness. On $D \times D \setminus \{(z,z) : z \in D\}$ you have $\frac{\rho(f(z),f(w))}{\rho(z,w)} < 1$. Show that you can continuously extend that quotient to the diagonal, and that the values on the diagonal are also $< 1$.

Comment: Thanks, that'll do it.